# Is there a way to force sp_send_dbmail to use ANSI, or to not include the Unicode prefix?

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-mail

This is pretty trivial, but if someone has the answer handy, I'd appreciate it.

I use the `msdb..sp_send_dbmail` stored procedure as a lightweight way to distribute simple reports.  This often entails producing a CSV.  However, the stored procedure includes the Unicode little-endian prefix FF FE.  This confuses Excel, causing it to not automatically parse the CSV into columns.

There are a number of workarounds: use a real reporting platform (we have Crystal, but it's never worked reliably); send the file to a little app that converts the file to ANSI and sends it on; use tab delimiters (my favorite); or educate the recipients about how to work with CSVs (just kidding, we all know that's not possible).

However, I'd love to just flip a switch somewhere and tell SQL Server to stop creating the attachments as Unicode, as I have no such need. I haven't found such a setting yet; is this possible?

Thanks!

---

EDIT

Based on Rohan's answer, this script in a SQL Agent job step *almost* works:

```
$reportQuery = "EXEC Routine..TopTenReviewsReport @DoNotLog = 1"
$filePath = "\\SQLBI001\RawData\TopTenReviewsReport.csv"
$mailQuery = "
  EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail
  @profile_name = 'X',
  @recipients = 'X',
  @subject = 'X',
  @file_attachments = '" + $filePath + "'"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -query $reportQuery | export-csv $filePath
$result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -query $mailQuery
```

The file now has a "#TYPE System.Data.DataRow" prefix, instead of 0xFF FE, but it's now ANSI, so that's something.

Comment: Clarification: I'm testing with Excel 2007, but 2K10 seems to have the same issue.  Removing the prefix is enough for Excel to parse the file, it does not have to be ANSI.

Comment: @Surfer513: Thanks for the tag, I could have sworn I tried that and it did not exist.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can generate the reports using powershell and then use DBMail to mail the attachments

```
Write-host "Running SQL Query to export to ANSI CSV file"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $dbQuery -ServerInstance $instanceName | export-csv $targetFileAnsi
Write-host "Running SQL Query to export to Unicode CSV file"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $dbQuery -ServerInstance $instanceName | export-csv $targetFileUnicode -encoding "unicode"


$dbMailQuery1 = "execute msdb..sp_send_dbmail 
@profile_name = 'msft_profile', 
@recipients = 'seths@microsoft.com', 
@subject = 'Email with Attachment - ANSI attachment', 
@body_format = 'TEXT', 
@body = 'This email has ANSI file attached to it', 
@file_attachments = 'c:\temp\result_ansi.csv' "
```

Source: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151031100000/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlagent/archive/2011/07/06/email-query-output-as-ansi-unicode-file-attachment-using-powershell-and-database-mail.aspx)

Comment: Hmm, and PowerShell is available via SQL Agent, which (I should have mentioned) is how I'm starting the jobs.  `Write-host` is not available in that context, but that's minor.  Unfortunately, the generated file has a different prefix: "#TYPE System.Data.DataRow".  It is indeed ANSI now, though.